# SQL finding value

Tags: sql-server

I would like to find `F20300000000` in this string:

---

```
0xE90300000000EA0300000000EB0300000000EC0300000000ED0300000000EE0300000000EF0300000000F00300000000F10300000000F20300000000F30300000000F40300000000F60300000000F70300000000E90B00000000010C000000000D0C000000003E0C000000005E0C000000005F0C00000000630C00000000811B000000008B1B00000000951B000000009F1B00000000A91B00000000B31B00000000BD1B00000000C71B00000000
```

---

I've used already the wildcard like

`LIKE '%F20300000000%'`  then I didn't get any result.

to make it clear, when my condition is true then it will show the name of the person who has the `F20300000000` in their field, so my problem now is it seems I don't know how to find `F20300000000` from the given value.

my query:

```
select C.Name
FROM
[SERVER01].[dbo].[character_table] AS C,
[SERVER01].[dbo].[achievement] AS T
WHERE C.CharacterIdx = T.CharacterIdx and T.AchievementData LIKE '%F20300000000%';
```

AchievementData Data Type is varbinary(4800)

Comment: What was your complete query?

Comment: It does work so what is the query you're using?

Comment: Thanks. What is the data type of T.AchievementData? Is it binary?

Comment: provide `desc achievement` also in question

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was discontinued with the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (more than **20 years** ago)

Answer (score 1):

Your column is likely to be binary so you should cast it to string:

```
select C.Name
FROM
[SERVER01].[dbo].[character_table] AS C,
[SERVER01].[dbo].[achievement] AS T
WHERE C.CharacterIdx = T.CharacterIdx and CONVERT(varchar(max), T.AchievementData, 2) LIKE '%F20300000000%';
```

Comment: tnx for the query but, i dint get any result.
im using MSSQL 2008 r2

Comment: Sorry, should have used convert instead of cast. See my edit now.

Comment: im sorry but still no result

Comment: See if this give you result: `select * from [SERVER01].[dbo].[achievement] AS T where CONVERT(varchar(max), T.AchievementData, 2) LIKE '%F20300000000%'`

Comment: @user2875703: Then please remove the confusing mysql tag from your question.

Comment: still no result, it just show's the columns but with empty set

Comment: Very weird, it works for me. Are you sure you have the right value in your column?

Comment: yes, some of the character id has the F20300000000 in their achievementdata

Comment: @user2875703: Hint (just an idea): Why don't you try Syzmon's solution but also including `CONVERT(varchar(max), T.AchievementData, 2)` in the `select` fieldlist and se what it outputs? That should help debug.